# How to know which type of data coming from back-end in ajax?

Tags: ajax

Working in front-end we never know the back-end language so how can I know whether the 
data coming from back-end is in `json` or in `text` or in `html` or in `xml`. We don't have an   authority or access to back-end language.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages declare this in the first line or 2... Why don't you just read the first few lines or the code?

Many languages will allow you to parse XML, not ideal to wrap it in a catch but it would work. However, you neglected to state what language you are using.

However, it may be worth while agreeing on a format, something like XML which you can then de-serialize ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `Content-Type` in `Response Headers` to know the response data type.